Questions / experiencing problems using BLEClient->connect with my ESP32s
I run a BLE central which would like to read data from a BLE peripheral using https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduinoble .
In order to do so, I connect it via connect(advertisedDevice).
Now here is the problem, sometimes the central experiences a complete hold during the call connect(bleAdvertisedDevice). The loop comes to a total stop, the call connect(bleAdvertisedDevice) never finishes.
Is there a way to have a timeout?
I have tried to use a try-catch block, but to no effect:
clock_t start = clock();
const int max_try_clocks = 5 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // 5 is the number of seconds 
                                               // we should keep trying for
try_again:
  try {
    connect(advertisedDevice)
  } catch (...) {
    if (clock() - start < max_try_clocks)
      return;
  }

Do you guys have any other recommendations as to how to handle this?
I am using Platformio (C++)

It is not clear what connect function you are calling. You should have instantiated a BLEDevice advertisedDevice, then call advertisedDevice.connect(). You may have omitted essential information in this question.
